# google-map-react: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-map-react

If i use marker tag then my component not working and it throwing an error some thing like this

[image]

**my code is:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMap, { Marker } from 'google-map-react';

class Maps extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {lat: 22.741033, lng: 81.102441},
    zoom: 5
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: ['AIzaSyAA1WZznnpeoP6hZz26UiARGNOhZhYLZek'] }}
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{height: '300px'}}
      >
      <Marker
        position={this.props.center}
      />
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}

export default Maps;
```

Comment: most of the time, that means you imported a component wrong (FYI)

Comment: ok how to import marker component @corvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue with exporting your component. 
I think `GoogleMap` is not exported by default in `react-google-maps`. Try importing it as a component.

`import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";`

Also you might wanna take a look at `withGoogleMap` component from [react-google-map](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/).

Adding my example code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";

const MapWithAMarker = withGoogleMap(props => {
    return (
        <GoogleMap defaultZoom={12}  defaultCenter={{ lat: props.marker.lat, lng: props.marker.lng }}>
            {props.marker &&
                <Marker label={props.marker.name}  position={{ lat: props.marker.lat, lng: props.marker.lng }} />
            }
        </GoogleMap>
    );
});

export default class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        const { marker } = this.props;

        return (
            <MapWithAMarker marker={marker} containerElement={<div className="mapContainer full-flex" />} mapElement={<div className="map" />} />
        );
    }
}

Map.propTypes = {
    marker: PropTypes.object
};
```

Comment: Oh sorry my bad.  Anyway, i didnt see any components naemd Marker available in [this library](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) which i hope i the correct one. Are you sure MArker component is availlable by default? All their example seems to use custom components.

Comment: Ok, Np but your solution is useful for someone, Thanks. @Noushad PP

Comment: np , you can post another answer. please don't change previous answer it may helpful for someone.@Noushad PP

Answer (score 1):

It seems [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) doesnt export a component named `Marker`
You can use your custom component as per their example [here](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react-examples/blob/master/web/flux/components/examples/x_simple/simple_map_page.jsx)